# Why is my Nikon D300S changing shutter speeds between shots?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, shutter-speed

Tonight while shooting a show I noticed that with each shutter release the shutter speed would change like it was bracketing for some reason. I don't know how or why it started but I need to get it fixed ASAP as I have a shoot on Monday.

Comment: You need to include some information about what shooting mode your camera is in and the nature of your subject.  I can think of two cases where what you describe would be completely normal behavior.